# How to Track POST & JSON requests via Google Analytics

Tags: json, api, post, google-analytics, tracking

I have a web system domain as https://yyyyy.abc.com/camp_req.php and users are sending API requests to this domain path via **POST & JSON** requests.

**Can i track these API calls via Google Analytics ??**

Header
[image]

Body
[image]

Comment: **"domain path via POST & JASON requests."**  Is JASON a framework i have just never heard of or are you talking about JSON?  It looks like your just using postman to send Json to api to me.

Comment: Yes, i just need to track who ever access the domain path. request comes as a POST and body has a JASON object

Comment: JASON or Json doesnt matter you will need to send the hit to google analytics yourself as a second call. you cant include calls to two diffrent endpoints in a single request